# WPF ListBox vertical scrollbar covers part of the items. How to resize the content to match the size of the ListBox?

Tags: wpf, image, listbox, scrollbar

i have a `ListBox` which is filled with images as items. works all fine and as intended so far. but the vertical scrollbar covers the right part of the images. how can i prevent that?

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Image Source="/BFH;component/Images/PackingPictures/1.jpg"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Image Source="/BFH;component/Images/PackingPictures/2.jpg"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

[image: without a scrollbar]
[image: with a scrollbar]

Comment: the ListBox parent is limited by size ?, it's look like you cancel the horizontal scroll -is he enable otherwise ?

Comment: the ListBox parent is a Grid. so it rather looks like this:
`<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Column="0">`
i had to cancel horizontal scroll, it would be enable otherwise.

Comment: How are you setting the width of the ListBox?

Comment: Then make the Grid bigger.

Comment: i am looking for a way to resize the images, no matter how big the Grid and therefore the ListBox is. i played with `Strech` but without success.

Comment: @el-nino `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` does not disable horizontal scrolling only hides horizontal scrollbar. Try with `Disable` otherwise your item is given more space horizontally then you can see

Comment: Use ItemsControl with ItemsPanel Template with no scrollviewer , like a StackPanel with horizontal orientation

Comment: So you are looking for a way to resize images but that is mentioned not where in the question.

Comment: i edited the question. it leads to the same answer though. dkozl had the right solution. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to dkozl, here is the right answer:

`HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` does not disable horizontal scrolling only hides horizontal scrollbar. Try with `Disable` otherwise your item is given more space horizontally then you can see.

so the solution is:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disable">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Image Source="/BFH;component/Images/PackingPictures/1.jpg"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Image Source="/BFH;component/Images/PackingPictures/2.jpg"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```